# Shared data across multiple microservices

Tags: architecture, microservices

I have the following scenario:

You can create an application via application-service. 
Before the application can be created specific information need to be checked. This information are distributed and only accessible via user-service and product-service.

First idea would be to send a message through all services via service bus and extend it by all necessary data and process the data at the end again in the application service:

->Application-service->User-service->Product-service->Applicaton-service

Second idea would be to store all relevant data redundant in all services. Means the application service has a copy of the user and product data.

Both ideas don´t feel right.

Are there any better approaches?

Comment: to store shared data across multiple micro services you can use distributed caching like [redis](https://redis.io/) or [memcached](https://memcached.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In service-oriented architecture like you are describing, it is perfectly normal to have data replicated in multiple services, with each extending the core entity specific to that service.

I suggest reconsidering your service boundaries, though.  A service is the technical authority for a specific business *process*.  Services are not meant to be aligned with business *data*.

For example, your `Product Service` and `User Service` sound like business data, and the `Application-Service` sounds too broad, without knowing more information.

Consider an `Order-Service` that needs information about the products.  It may subscribe to `ProductCreated` events from the `Product-Service` to populate itself with product information, although likely just a ProductID.  The `Order-Service` does not need to know the product's name, description, price (this may live in the `Billing` service), etc.

Since a service is the one and only authority for a business process, it therefore should also own the user interface.  Composite UI patterns allow rending a single page with components from multiple services.  The `Application-Service` would host the page and the glue that pulls the components together.  For more information on that, I found [Micro Frontends](https://martinfowler.com/articles/micro-frontends.html) a good read.